# how to handle multiple jqgrid instances on same page with ashx file ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid, multiple-instances, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm using Webform and Jqgrid to display master-detail information on same page.
Here is my Jqgrid definition:

- Master JQGrid:

`$("#MachineListGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'AdminHandler.ashx',
    datatype: "json",
    ...
});`

- Detail JQGrid:

`$("#MachineDetailListGrid").jqGrid({
    url:'AdminHandler.ashx',
    datatype: "json",
    ...
});`

my question is, how does ashx file identify data to return json data back to the correct jqgrid?
I'd looked at the same between aspx and ashx from [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609442/Using-JqGrid-in-ASP-NET) but the tutorial only gave sample one `JQGrid` on page.

on the code, here is the way to capture the request:
`System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection forms = context.Request.Form;`

Answer (score 1):

The way that will solve the problem is to have two url - one for the master and another for the detail

```
$("#MachineListGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'AdminHandlerMaster.ashx',
    datatype: "json",
    ...
});

$("#MachineDetailListGrid").jqGrid({
    url:'AdminHandlerDatil.ashx',
    datatype: "json",
    ...
});
```

If you can't do this you may identify it with additional parameter in the post data something like this

```
$("#MachineListGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'AdminHandler.ashx',
    datatype: "json",
    postData : { gridtype:"master"},
    ...
});

$("#MachineDetailListGrid").jqGrid({
    url:'AdminHandler.ashx',
    datatype: "json",
    postData : { gridtype:"detail"},
    ...
});
```

In the response you will need to get the gridtype  parameter to identify the master and detail data

Comment: Hi @Tony Tomov,
Thank you for your suggestion. I prefer to option #2.
But I'm not sure what is different between `data`  and `postData` in AJAX.

Comment: postData object add parameter to the url. This is equivalent to `url:'AdminHandler.ashx?gridtype=detail'`  and the same for the master instead of the postData